# Confused my the meaning of this character's thought when he's facing against a monster 脳味噌の端っこの方で状況を整理する

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**A character is facing against a monster, and I don't understand 1 part of his thought here. Hope someone can explain to me its correct meaning.**

**脳味噌の端っこの方で状況を整理する (my guess: " I'm analyzing the situation/ my circumstance with the edge of my brain " ???)**

More context :
こちらの様子を窺い、隙あらば飛びかかる気配を見せる目の前の“ナニか”。

（左右は壁……。道幅は刀を振り回すにはちょっと狭い感じ。となれば、基本は突きで対応するしかない）

（逃げ道は後ろのみ……。うーん、大通りに戻った方が良いかな）

（けどこいつ……足の筋肉の付き方で、すばしっこそうなのが見てとれるんだよなぁ……広いところだと逆に不利か……？）

**相手からは片時も目を離さず、脳味噌の端っこの方で状況を整理する。**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not **with** but ***in** the corner of the brain*. It is similar to *at the back of my mind*.

Basically, it says the character does the thinking without losing the focus on the opponent.

Comment: oh so he's thinking in his mind.... Someone give this novel author an award please !